# Why are there exceptions after changing Webservice Url dynamically?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, dynamic, webforms

In my webform project, I let the user input a new WSDL url.

I already set the property of the webservice as dynamic, and use

```
service.url = strNewWebserviceUrl
```

But when I try to call the function of the webservice, the following error is always thrown:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Possible SOAP version mismatch: Envelope namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/ was unexpected. Expecting http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/. at 
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall) at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters) at WebApplication2.EL8SceenService.ScreenService.executeScreen(OperationContext context, String msoName) in D:\CSharp\WebApplication2TRY\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\Web References\EL8SceenService\Reference.cs:line

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message, it appears as though you are including the ?wsdl portion of the URL instead of the straight URL to the web service.

Comment: But I do need that ?wsdl part

Comment: Excellent and welcome to Stackoverflow! Remember, if an answer solves or helps you solve a question, you should click the checkmark and up arrow next to the question so that future visitors to the question know that this is what solved your problem.